# Unable to read file 'subjFiles(1).name'. No such file or directory

Tags: matlab

I'm using some codes that called specific function.
in line 17 of this function I get the error

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in generateExpReport (line 17)
>               checkPValuesField                  = subjFiles(1).name;

the function up to line 20 is like this:

```
function [] = generateExpReport(copyDir,resultDir,params)
% Syntax

methodNames          = fieldnames(params.methods);
numMethods           = length(methodNames);

    for i = 1 : numMethods
        cd(resultDir)
        numTargets                         = length(params.methods.(methodNames{i,1}).idTargets);
        idDrivers                          = params.methods.(methodNames{i,1}).idDrivers;
        nameFiles                          = [methodNames{i,1} '*.mat'];
        subjFiles                          = dir(nameFiles);
        numSubj                            = length(subjFiles);
        significanceOnDrivers              = zeros(numSubj,numTargets);
        matrixTransferEntropy              = zeros(numSubj,(numTargets)+1);
%         check if the pValues matrix is present
        checkPValuesField                  = load(subjFiles(1).name);
        fields                             = fieldnames(checkPValuesField);
        nameFields                         = checkPValuesField.(fields{1,1});
```

I can't find the problem
please help me:(( what's wrong with

```
checkPValuesField                  = load(subjFiles(1).name);
```

Comment: Are you sure that a file named "subjFiles(1).name" exists in your system?

Comment: I used this but it caused below error:
Unable to read file 'subjFiles(1).name'. No such file or directory.

i'm really new to matlab
how can I do this(The name field does not include the path, so if the files are not in your current path you need to also use the folder field to create an absolute path to your file.)?

Comment: There are no files in whatever `resultDir` is that match whatever `[methodNames{i,1} '*.mat']` is. This means `subjFiles` is empty so attempting to index it will result in the error.

Comment: thanx a lot! ^^